# import pygame fails

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, pygame

I have installed python 2.6.6  and pygame 2.6 from here:
http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.6.msi

However, when I try to run this simple program, I get a an error:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.quit ()
```

The error says:

> unresolved import:pygame

What could it be?

Edit: 
When I am doing

```
import pygame
```

in C:\Python26\python.exe , the interpreter, it works ok.
So it is probably an Eclipse problem.
Anyone has an idea what to do?

Comment: Is pygame in your PYTHONPATH variable??

Comment: **where** are you running this program ? What do you get if you do `import pygame` in python shell ?

Comment: @joaquin in python shell it is ok. It happens only when I select run in Eclipse. Perhaps I need to set up the path there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before

```
 import pygame
```

add the lines

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

if the path to `pygame` isn't shown, then you've  don't have the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set correctly.

Comment: If you're using PyDev on Eclipse, then Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python -> Libraries tab on the bottom half. That tab says "System PYTHONPATH". Pygame should have been installed in your C:/Python26/lib/site-packages folder, and that folder should be visible in that bottom half of the PyDev config screen.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo pip install pygame
```

And then try:

```
import pygame
```

That should work for you.

Comment: I guess it might be useful on Linux, I used Windows.

Comment: yeah right, it works on linux but you can install pip on windows as well https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows and then perform that same process. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

If Eclipse can not find Pygame when you import it. There is an issue with Pygame being in Python's path. If you are trying to run Pygame through Eclipse like I am. The easiest way is to uninstal Pygame. Download Pygame from here.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Make sure it is the correct version of Pygame for your version of Python. When installing if it does not find the path by itself you will need to place it in yourself. My version of Pygame placed itself in the correct path.

To check Python's path with out going in to preference. You can type the code.

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

If it is showing it in your path and it is still not working. You have the wrong version for you current Python. If every thing is right then your code should work. You can use the code below to print your Pygame version.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
print (pygame.ver)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I suggest you check if you have created a path when you have installed your version of Python. For create the path, or check it, just go to the panel control, click `"System and Security"` then `"System"`, click on `"Advanced system settings"` and on `"Environment variables"`. Now you only need to click on `"Path"` and `"Edit"`: now you can see if you have already created a path or if you need to create a new path.

In the second case click on `"new"`. Find YOUR path where Python is on computer and put it on string. Click "OK". Restart your computer, go to cmd and write

```
pip3 install pygame
```

then go to IDLE and run this simple code:

```
import pygame
```

I hope that you successfully installed `pygame`.

If it doesn't work, reinstall python and check to create a path during download.